# how to get partial data from url ,these code is giving me failed to decode error python3.0

Tags: python-requests, network-programming

can anyone help me how to get partial data from url ,these code is giving me failed to decode error

```
import  requests
url = "http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt"

start=24
end=30
headers = {"Range":f"bytes={start}-{end}"}
r = requests.get(url,stream=True,headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a range of the resource, which the server reponds with, but due to the standard header `Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"`, the server sends the bytes back of the encoded resource. In order to retrieve the non-encoded bytes use the following header:

```
import  requests
url = "http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt"

start=24
end=30
headers = {"Range":f"bytes={start}-{end}", "Accept-Encoding": None}
r = requests.get(url,stream=True,headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```